# MS Excel increments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm new to spreadsheets and really struggling to find a solution to what I'm sure should be a really simple problem.

I have a list of twenty teams. Each week they take part in a competition. Ten points are awarded to the winning team, nine pts to second place, eight to third place, down to one point for every team placed tenth or lower.

My worksheet has three columns: Place, Team Name, Total Points (place is the finishing position in this weeks competition).

I have the teams listed in Column 2 and I am trying to increment the Total Points column according to the value I enter in the Place column.

If I entered 1 in the Place column, I would like to increment the Total Points for that Team by 10 (being the points accumulated by the team finishing first each week). Entering 4 would increment the Total Points by 7 (seven points being scored for finishing fourth).

If I can do this I would then look at creating a pivot table to sort the teams in order of Total Points in descending order.

I'd appreciate any pointers for this.

Comment: This would probably need VBA, especially for the case when the Place column is later modified.

Comment: Add `11 - place` points.

Comment: modifying @MGonet comment, the formula should be more along the lines of: `=11 - MIN(place,10)`.

Comment: @gns100 if I knew how to "accept" your answer I would. I haven't tested it yet but it does seem to make sense. I'll get back here with the results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this formula?

```
=11-A2
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, no. I'm looking at this and seeing resulting negative values (eg 19th place should be awarded 1pt but 11-19 would result in Total Points of -8). Further, I hoped to increment the existing scores from the previous week, so if Team A has 28 points in the Total column and they come 4th this week, the Total would = 35 (28 + 7 for finishing 4th this week). I'm starting to think this is beyond Excel?